# Si el registro es repetido no mostrar

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesitaría hacer una consulta, pero que no me saque los productos repetidos, mi consulta es la siguiente

```
SELECT c.id, p.nombre AS nombre_paciente, 
       p.nombre AS nombre_paciente_search, 
       p.apellidos AS apellidos_paciente, 
       p.historia, c.fecha, c.hora, c.codigo_personal, 
       c.estado, c.otros,per.nombre, per.apellidos
FROM citas c 
INNER JOIN pacientes p 
ON historia_paciente = historia 
INNER JOIN personal per ON codigo_personal = per.id 
ORDER BY fecha ASC 
LIMIT 100
```

Necesito que los repetidos de **nombre_paciente_search** no los saque

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Os pongo más o menos en situación tengo 2 tablas 1 que se llama citas y otra pacientes, nombre_paciente saca el nombre del paciente de la tabla citas y claro un paciente puede tener varias citas, entonces yo quiero que en un sitio me aparezcan todas las citas, que eso ya lo hace y en otro sitio quiero sacar solamente el nombre de los pacientes pero sin salir repetidos

Comment: ¿Has probado con: `DISTINCT(p.nombre) as nombre_paciente_search` ? ¿Puedes mostrar los registros que te saca? quizás necesites agrupar por p.nombre

Comment: Hola @Parra gracias por responder he probado `SELECT c.id, p.nombre AS nombre_paciente, DISTINCT (p.nombre) AS nombre_paciente_search, p.apellidos AS apellidos_paciente, p.historia, c.fecha, c.hora, c.codigo_personal ,c.estado, c.otros,per.nombre.. ` y tambien he probado sin los paréntesis

Comment: y al hacer dicha consulta que obtienes @MiguelÁngelMartín?, agrega por favor una muestra de los datos de entrada y una muestra de los datos que esperas que salgan en la consulta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo que necesitas es GROUP BY:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

```
SELECT c.id, p.nombre AS nombre_paciente, 
       p.nombre AS nombre_paciente_search, 
       p.apellidos AS apellidos_paciente, 
       p.historia, c.fecha, c.hora, c.codigo_personal, 
       c.estado, c.otros,per.nombre, per.apellidos
FROM citas c 
INNER JOIN pacientes p 
ON historia_paciente = historia 
INNER JOIN personal per ON codigo_personal = per.id 
GROUP BY nombre_paciente_search
ORDER BY fecha ASC 
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Omite muchos resultados si quito el LIMIT